# jquery load function not invoking spring boot controller to replace thymeleaf template fragment

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to load content into the following fragment. I've confirmed that this fragment works when I do a basic mapping to an html template.

```
<div id="fbtresult" th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(fbts)}" th:fragment="fbtList">
    <h2>Frequent Bought Together List</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Main Product Id</th>
            <th>FBT 1 Product ID </th>
            <th>FBT 2 Product ID</th>
            <th>BSR</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="fbt : ${fbts}">
            <td th:text="${fbt.id}"><a href="/fbt/${fbt.id}">Id</a></td>
            <td th:text="${fbt?.mainProduct?.asin}">main product asin</td>
            <td th:text="${fbt.sproductFbt1 != null} ? ${fbt.sproductFbt1.asin} : ''">product fbt1 asin</span>
            <td th:text="${fbt.sproductFbt2 != null} ? ${fbt.sproductFbt2.asin} : ''">product fbt2 asin</span>
            <td th:text="${fbt.bsr}">bsr</td>        
            <td><a th:href="${ '/fbt/' + fbt.id}">View</a></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
</div>
```

However I'm attempting to use the following query load statement that is within a canvasjs click function. I've confirmed that jquery is loading and the console will log the url on click of the canvasjs chart.

```
                    click: function (e) {
                        var asin = /*[[${asin}]]*/ 'null';
                        var url = "/FBTChartfbtrequest?fbt=2&asin=" + asin + "&collectdate=" + e.dataPoint.x;
                        console.log(url);
                        $("#fbtresult").load(url);
                    },
```

However the following controller is not being executed by $("#fbtresult").load(url); which is clear from the log.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/FBTChartfbtrequest")
        public String FBTChartfbtrequest(@RequestParam("fbt") String fbt,
                @RequestParam("asin") String asin, @RequestParam("collectdate") String collectdate, Model model) {
            System.out.println("ZZZZ requestFBTCHar with asin " + asin + " and collectdate " + collectdate);

...
                    model.addAttribute("fbts", fbtService.findByASINInFBT1andDateRange(asin, convertUtilToSql(date), convertUtilToSql(date)));
....
            return "results :: fbtList";
        }
```

I've confirmed that I can load a new page with the /FBTChartfbtrequest?fbt=2&asin=" + asin + "&collectdate=" + e.dataPoint.x; url when doing a redirection using window.location.href = url;

my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The http://localhost:8086/FBTMetricsRequest is visible in the network tab even before i click on the graph and clicking on the graph doesn't make a change in the network view. 
[image: Graph and network tab]

Any ideas why the jquery load function is not invoking the controller function?

Comment: Can you check in your network log, jquery sending request to server. As of my assumption it should send request to server. Please post network log screenshot.

Comment: @swarooppallapothu I've added the screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the load function should be adjusted to as follows in order to use the fragments logic

```
var url = "/FBTChartfbtrequest?";
$('#fbtresult').load(url, "fbt=1&asin=" + asin + "&collectdate=" + e.dataPoint.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Ajax Centric solution is as follows. I would still like to get a template centric version running however.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    success: function (res) {
        $("#fbtresult").html(res);
    },
    fail: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

});
```

With the following controller adjustment

```
@GetMapping(value = "/FBTChartfbtrequest")
public String FBTChartfbtrequest(@RequestParam("fbt") String fbt,
@RequestParam("asin") String asin, @RequestParam("collectdate") String collectdate, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("fbts", fbtService.findByASINInFBT1andDateRange(asin, convertUtilToSql(date), convertUtilToSql(date)));
    return "fbtList";
}
```

And HTML Modification

```
<div id="fbtresult">
     <!-- Dynamic content using ajax -->
</div>
```

This is not as desireable as having the ability to reference the objects to create new links for example.

[Id](/fbt/$%7Bfbt.id%7D)
                main product asin
                product fbt1 asin
                product fbt2 asin
                bsr
                View

I suppose I can generate the html in the java application that includes those links. I guess I prefer creating the dynamic html in the template view.